# Primefaces listener on selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss

I've problems with the primefaces ajax call listener.
(primefaces 4.0 , JSF 2.0 , JBoss 6.1.1 )

This is the selectOneMenu that I defined:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="sistema" label="Sistema" value="#{searchSchedulingBean.selectedSystem}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{searchSchedulingBean.systemChangeListener}" 
        process="@this"
        event="change"
        update="autostrada"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{searchSchedulingBean.systemsList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And this is the main part of my managedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchSchedulingBean implements Serializable {
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("init executed");
        ...
    }

    public void systemChangeListener() {
        logger.info("listener executed");
        ...
    }
```

When I open the page the log tell me that the init method is executed and the selectOneMenus are correctly populated so I assume that the managed bean is working.
If I change the selectOneMenu that I wrote above the selectOneMenu that I want to modify is influenced because it is the only selectOneMenu of the page that selects the initial value of the list but the entries are not updated as I want and the method systemChangeListener is not executed because I don't see "listener executed" in the log.

I tried to change the managed bean from @ViewedScoped to @RequestScoped for debug purposes and it seems that the change of selectOneMenu fires an event because I can see on the log "init executed" each time that I modify the menu selection ( the ManagedBean is recreated to manage the event) but I don't see on the log "listener executed" so the listener method is not executed. No exception are thrown. 
Any idea to solve?

EDIT1:
I tried your suggestions but it still doesn't work.
I used @ManagedBean @RequestScoped as managed bean class annotation, and from the log I can see that the managed bean is initiated each time that the selectonemenu changes but the listener method is not executed.
Could it be a compatibility problem between JBoss 6.1.1 (Jsf 2.0) and Primefaces 4.0?
If yes which version of primefaces is suggested for JBoss 6.1.1?
Is there any particular configuration needed to use primefaces?
For completeness I write here the deployment descriptors

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="false"> 
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>programmazioni.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/PresentationModule</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

And those are the dependencies that I imported in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1101-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: have you tried having `public void systemChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)` ?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I believe you don't need the process and event attributes on the listener - just delete them. What types are selectedSystem and systemsList?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

Replace

```
<p:ajax listener="#{searchSchedulingBean.systemChangeListener}"
```

by

```
<p:ajax listener="#{searchSchedulingBean.systemChangeListener()}"
```

**Solution 2 :**

Replace

```
systemChangeListener()
```

by

```
systemChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent evt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This is working for me

```
<p:ajax listener="#{searchSchedulingBean.systemChangeListener}" update="autostrada"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately it still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I just solved, the problem was caused by the attribute value of selectOneMenu that must be of String type but in my ManagedBean I setted as SelectItem type.

Comment: Next time put the entire code, but I doubt that was the only problem. You have changed your EL expression or the method signature.

Comment: Sorry I tried to put only the code that I considered important to not overcharge the post, but I made a mistake :(
It works without the '()' in the p:ajax tag "listener" attribute and with the method signature that doesn't have parameters.
Thanks for your interest to my problem and sorry again if I have not written the full code.